# Javascriptのコンストラクタ内のjQueryイベントハンドラからメンバを参照する方法はありますか？

Tags: javascript, jquery

具体的には以下です。

```
var Sample = function(str){
    this.str = str;

    $('#btn').click(function(){
         alert(str);
    });
}
```

クリックイベントハンドラからsrtを出力します。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

イベントハンドラの中で`this.str`のように使いたいという事でしょうか？

この場合、古典的な方法として、`this`を変数に代入しておいてから使う方法があります。
一般的には`self`という変数名を使います。

```
var Sample = function(str){
    this.str = str;

    var self = this;
    $('#btn').click(function(){
         alert(self.str);
    });
}
Sample("aaa");
```

もう一つの方法として、`bind()`を使用する方法があります。
[Function.prototype.bind() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)
bind()の第一引数で指定したオブジェクトが、そのfunction内でのthisになります。

```
var Sample = function(str){
    this.str = str;

    $('#btn').click(function(){
         alert(this.str);
    }.bind(this));
}
Sample("bbb");
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。まさしく後者の方法を探していました。

Answer (score 3):

ES2015ではアロー関数([arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions))を使うことでthisの束縛が出来るようになりました。

```
var Sample = function(str){
 this.str = str; 
 $('#btn').click(()=>{
     alert(this.str); 
  }); 
};
```

なお、ES2015は古いブラウザ等では対応していなかったりするのでbabel等でトランスパイルするのが現実的ですが。

(なお、トランスパイルすると`var _this`のような変数が自動的に使用されます。`self`と同じ手法ですね。)